# Multiple `if` conditions with `jq` and `grep` incorrectly matches and returns true when it shouldn't match at all

Tags: json, bash, if-statement, grep, jq

I have a `json` file:

```
cat myjsonfile.json

{
    "directory": true,
    "condition": "",
    "specialCondition": "",
    "dataFiles": "",
    "nonstandard-protocol": true
}
```

`specialCondition` is standardized and can be empty or have a `matched` or `unmatched` state.

I simply want to `translate` those conditions to another state when `nonstandard-protocol` is `false`.

So I wrote this in my bash script.

```
if [[  "jq '.specialCondition' myjsonfile.json | grep -q 'matched'"  &&  "jq '."nonstandard-protocol"' myjsonfile.json | grep -q 'false'"  ]]; then echo 'MATCHED' | cat > protocol_result.txt; fi
if [[  "jq '.specialCondition' myjsonfile.json | grep -q 'unmatched'"  &&  "jq '."nonstandard-protocol"' myjsonfile.json | grep -q 'false'"  ]]; then echo 'NOTMATCHED' | cat > protocol_result.txt; fi
```

However, this returns incorrect results. When I run the script, I always see that first it writes `MATCHED` to my `protocol_result.txt` and then with the second `if` line it writes `NOTMATCHED` to the file! While it shouldn't write anything at all... Why is this happening?

Comment: A string is always true. Hence `[[ "something" && "something else" ]]` always sets status code 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the `if` statements to `jq` and have it output whatever you want.

The following example prints nothing `""` if `nonstandard-protocol` is true, or `specialCondition` is neither `matched` nor `unmatched`. Otherwise it'll print `MATCHED` or `NOTMATCHED`, depending on the content of `specialCondition`:

```sh
jq --raw-output '
  if ."nonstandard-protocol" then ""
  else if .specialCondition == "matched" then "MATCHED"
    elif .specialCondition == "unmatched" then "NOTMATCHED"
    else "" end
  end
' myjsonfile.json > protocol_result.txt
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/L2rO3KOimC)

Note: Using `""` will print nothing as expected, but followed by a newline because it had an output (which essentially is an empty line, then). If you don't want that, change `""` to `empty`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually execute your `grep` command, if you need its status code:

```sh
if jq .specialCondition myjsonfile.json | tee protocol_result.txt | grep -q matched  &&  jq '."nonstandard-protocol"' myjsonfile.json | tee -a protocol_result.txt | grep -q false 
then 
  ..... 
fi
```

Comment: `jq .nonstandard-protocol` will fail because jq will treat it as a subtraction while `protocol` is not defined. Put quotes around non-trivial field names.

Comment: @pmf : I guess this applies then also to the word `.specialCondition`? Could you please check my edited answer?

Comment: The necessity for quoting field names only applies to non-trivial names (`specialCondition` is considered trivial, or "identifier-like" as phrased in the [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#ObjectIdentifier-Index%3A.foo%2C.foo.bar), as it contains no special characters such as `-`). However, quotes, if used, must enclose only the field name, not the selector `.`, thus `."nonstandard-protocol"` would be the right way to write it.

Comment: Likewise, if the whole jq filter, which to the shell is a string, contains non-trivial characters such as spaces, brackets or indeed quotes (which would be swallowed by the shell), either escape those characters (as you have tried to, but with the right ones), or enclose the whole filter in single quotes (which is generally the preferred way to do it). I have edited your answer accordingly.

Comment: @pmf : Thank you a lot for your help! I first thought that the period also would be invalid, but I understand that it's only the `-` which upsets jq.